# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not locate PropertySource and the fail fast property is set, failing

Tags: docker, microservices

The default generated application for microservices is not starting up. It seems that SpringBoot is not being able to connect to Registry.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not locate PropertySource and the fail fast property is set, failing

at org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.locate(ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.java:110) ~[spring-cloud-config-client-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:1.1.0.RELEASE]

at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.config.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration.initialize(PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration.java:89) ~[spring-cloud-context-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:1.1.0.RELEASE]

at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.applyInitializers(SpringApplication.java:640) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:343) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]

at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]

at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]

at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]

at com.piggymetrics.registry.RegistryApplication.main(RegistryApplication.java:12) [classes/:na]

Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://config:8888/registry/default": config; nested exception is java.net.UnknownHostException: config

at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:607) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]

at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:557) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]

at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:475) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]

at org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.getRemoteEnvironment(ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.java:130) ~[spring-cloud-config-client-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:1.1.0.RELEASE]

at org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.locate(ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.java:81) ~[spring-cloud-config-client-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:1.1.0.RELEASE]
... 7 common frames omitted
```

Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: config
    Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: config

```
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184) ~[na:1.8.0_131]

at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_131]

at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_131]

at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538) ~[na:1.8.0_131]

at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180) ~[na:1.8.0_131]

at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463) ~[na:1.8.0_131]

at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558) ~[na:1.8.0_131]

at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:242) ~[na:1.8.0_131]

at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:339) ~[na:1.8.0_131]

at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_131]

at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1202) ~[na:1.8.0_131]

at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1138) ~[na:1.8.0_131]

at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1032) ~[na:1.8.0_131]

at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:966) ~[na:1.8.0_131]

at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:80) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]

at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]

at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]

at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:93) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]

at org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator$BasicAuthorizationInterceptor.intercept(ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.java:179) ~[spring-cloud-config-client-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:1.1.0.RELEASE]

at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:85) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]

at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:69) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]

at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]

at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]

at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:596) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
... 11 common frames omitted

2017-07-04 12:17:49.602  INFO 21730 --- [           main] .b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener : Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/home/hp/Bureau/PiggyMetrics-master/registry/target/classes/, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server/1.1.0.RELEASE/spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-starter/1.1.0.RELEASE/spring-cloud-starter-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.7/logback-classic-1.1.7.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.1.7/logback-core-1.1.7.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.21/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.21.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.21/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.21.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.7.21/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.21.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.16/snakeyaml-1.16.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-context/1.1.0.RELEASE/spring-cloud-context-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-crypto/4.0.4.RELEASE/spring-security-crypto-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-commons/1.1.0.RELEASE/spring-cloud-commons-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-rsa/1.0.1.RELEASE/spring-security-rsa-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/org/bouncycastle/bcpkix-jdk15on/1.47/bcpkix-jdk15on-1.47.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.47/bcprov-jdk15on-1.47.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-server/1.1.0.RELEASE/spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-server-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-web-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/8.0.33/tomcat-embed-core-8.0.33.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-el/8.0.33/tomcat-embed-el-8.0.33.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-logging-juli/8.0.33/tomcat-embed-logging-juli-8.0.33.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/8.0.33/tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.33.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-validation/1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-validation-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.2.4.Final/hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.3.0.Final/jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.1.0/classmate-1.1.0.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-expression-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-actuator/1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-actuator-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-actuator/1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-actuator-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-freemarker/1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-freemarker-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/org/freemarker/freemarker/2.3.23/freemarker-2.3.23.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context-support/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-context-support-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-netflix-core/1.1.0.RELEASE/spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client/1.1.0.RELEASE/spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/com/netflix/eureka/eureka-client/1.4.6/eureka-client-1.4.6.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jettison/jettison/1.3.7/jettison-1.3.7.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/stax/stax-api/1.0.1/stax-api-1.0.1.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/com/netflix/netflix-commons/netflix-eventbus/0.3.0/netflix-eventbus-0.3.0.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/javax/ws/rs/jsr311-api/1.1.1/jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/com/netflix/servo/servo-core/0.10.1/servo-core-0.10.1.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/com/netflix/servo/servo-internal/0.10.1/servo-internal-0.10.1.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/com/sun/jersey/jersey-core/1.19.1/jersey-core-1.19.1.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/com/sun/jersey/jersey-client/1.19.1/jersey-client-1.19.1.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/com/sun/jersey/contribs/jersey-apache-client4/1.19.1/jersey-apache-client4-1.19.1.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.2/httpclient-4.5.2.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.4/httpcore-4.4.4.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.9/commons-codec-1.9.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/com/google/inject/guice/4.0/guice-4.0.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/com/netflix/governator/governator-api/1.12.10/governator-api-1.12.10.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/com/sun/jersey/jersey-servlet/1.19.1/jersey-servlet-1.19.1.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/com/sun/jersey/jersey-server/1.19.1/jersey-server-1.19.1.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/com/netflix/eureka/eureka-core/1.4.6/eureka-core-1.4.6.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-core/1.10.30/aws-java-sdk-core-1.10.30.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-ec2/1.10.30/aws-java-sdk-ec2-1.10.30.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-autoscaling/1.9.3/aws-java-sdk-autoscaling-1.9.3.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-sts/1.9.3/aws-java-sdk-sts-1.9.3.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-route53/1.9.3/aws-java-sdk-route53-1.9.3.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/com/netflix/governator/governator/1.12.10/governator-1.12.10.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/com/netflix/governator/governator-core/1.12.10/governator-core-1.12.10.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm/5.0.4/asm-5.0.4.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/woodstox/woodstox-core-asl/4.4.1/woodstox-core-asl-4.4.1.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/javax/xml/stream/stax-api/1.0-2/stax-api-1.0-2.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/com/netflix/archaius/archaius-core/0.7.4/archaius-core-0.7.4.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/3.0.1/jsr305-3.0.1.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/javax/inject/javax.inject/1/javax.inject-1.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/jackson-dataformat-xml/2.6.6/jackson-dataformat-xml-2.6.6.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations/2.6.6/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.6.6.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/woodstox/stax2-api/3.1.4/stax2-api-3.1.4.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/com/thoughtworks/xstream/xstream/1.4.2/xstream-1.4.2.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/xmlpull/xmlpull/1.1.3.1/xmlpull-1.1.3.1.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/xpp3/xpp3_min/1.1.4c/xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-starter-archaius/1.1.0.RELEASE/spring-cloud-starter-archaius-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/commons-configuration/commons-configuration/1.8/commons-configuration-1.8.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/commons-lang-2.6.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.6.6/jackson-annotations-2.6.6.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.6.6/jackson-core-2.6.6.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/18.0/guava-18.0.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-starter-ribbon/1.1.0.RELEASE/spring-cloud-starter-ribbon-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/com/netflix/ribbon/ribbon/2.1.5/ribbon-2.1.5.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/com/netflix/ribbon/ribbon-transport/2.1.5/ribbon-transport-2.1.5.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/io/reactivex/rxnetty-contexts/0.4.9/rxnetty-contexts-0.4.9.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/io/reactivex/rxnetty-servo/0.4.9/rxnetty-servo-0.4.9.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/com/netflix/hystrix/hystrix-core/1.5.2/hystrix-core-1.5.2.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/org/hdrhistogram/HdrHistogram/2.1.7/HdrHistogram-2.1.7.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/io/reactivex/rxnetty/0.4.9/rxnetty-0.4.9.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-codec-http/4.0.27.Final/netty-codec-http-4.0.27.Final.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-codec/4.0.27.Final/netty-codec-4.0.27.Final.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-handler/4.0.27.Final/netty-handler-4.0.27.Final.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-transport-native-epoll/4.0.27.Final/netty-transport-native-epoll-4.0.27.Final.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-common/4.0.27.Final/netty-common-4.0.27.Final.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-buffer/4.0.27.Final/netty-buffer-4.0.27.Final.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-transport/4.0.27.Final/netty-transport-4.0.27.Final.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/com/netflix/ribbon/ribbon-core/2.1.5/ribbon-core-2.1.5.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/com/netflix/ribbon/ribbon-httpclient/2.1.5/ribbon-httpclient-2.1.5.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.2/commons-collections-3.2.2.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/com/netflix/netflix-commons/netflix-commons-util/0.1.1/netflix-commons-util-0.1.1.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/com/netflix/ribbon/ribbon-loadbalancer/2.1.5/ribbon-loadbalancer-2.1.5.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/com/netflix/netflix-commons/netflix-statistics/0.1.1/netflix-statistics-0.1.1.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/io/reactivex/rxjava/1.1.5/rxjava-1.1.5.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/com/netflix/ribbon/ribbon-eureka/2.1.5/ribbon-eureka-2.1.5.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.21/slf4j-api-1.7.21.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-starter-config/1.1.0.RELEASE/spring-cloud-starter-config-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-config-client/1.1.0.RELEASE/spring-cloud-config-client-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.6.6/jackson-databind-2.6.6.jar, file:/home/hp/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/4.2.6.RELEASE/spring-core-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar]
```

// console view

Comment: Would you add your code as well?

Comment: What about your docker conf. ?

Comment: https://github.com/sqshq/PiggyMetrics

Comment: // dockerFileFROM java:8-jre
MAINTAINER Alexander Lukyanchikov <sqshq@sqshq.com>

ADD ./target/config.jar /app/
CMD ["java", "-Xmx200m", "-jar", "/app/config.jar"]

HEALTHCHECK --interval=10s --timeout=3s CMD curl -f http://localhost:8888/health || exit 1

EXPOSE 8888

Comment: @ikbel jaouadi - What is the solution for this issue ?